# How can I log all my dockers containers to separate windows in a Powershell script?

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with multiple containers in it. When I run the `docker-compose up` I get all my logs in the same window. I am now trying to write a script that would start one Powershell window for every docker and attach to it. This script will be run after my containers are started. My Goal, is to have one window per container so I can debug more easily. Here is the script I have so far

```
$containersInformation = (docker ps -q)
#get containerID
$containersInformation.ForEach({
    $containerID = $_
    Write-Output $containerID
    #get open each container log in separate window
    Start-Process powershell{docker attach $containerID}
    Write-Output "====================="
})
```

The script run but after it executed it close all the windows. If I add the `-Wait` it just wait on one window. I also tried running in detached mode and I tried putting this codes at the end to ensure the windows are not closing before the escape key is pressed.

```
Do {
    $Key = [Console]::ReadKey($True)
    Write-Host $Key.Key
   } While ( $Key.Key -NE [ConsoleKey]::Escape )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would you do that. I would run docker-compose with --detach (or -d, it's the same) and use docker logs to check the logs of each docker

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/